# how to have a nested "not" as an "each" exclusion

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change some of the attributes of all anchors on a page, except where the class is `.q`, but EXCEPT for a `.q` anchor where the innertext of the anchor is `>images<`.

I got as far as `$("a").not(".q").each(function(){` etc. How do I now exclude that one (or more) `.q` anchor(s) from the previous `.not` exclusion? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest manually filtering:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if( !this.className.match(/\bq\b/) || (this.textContent || this.innerText) == ">images<") {
        // do stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter()` like this -

```
$('a').filter(function () {
    var text = $.trim(this.innerText);
    var isQ = $(this).is('.q');
    return !(isQ && text !== 'images');
}).addClass('red');
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/tLFjA/1/

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Nice function, didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/HsVHq/

**code**

```
$("a.q").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "images")
        $(this).css("background", "yellow");
});
```